# Samsung Galaxy S4 Mail App not syncing while set to Automatic sync(Push)

Tags: applications, samsung, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, stock-email-app

It does sync automatically(push) only when I have opened the app. But today, eventhough I had it opened it didn't.
I would like my phone to sync auto even after I close the app.

I would also download another email app if necessary.

Android version 5.0.1

Comment: Who operates the mail server? Android 5 has a very limited support of modern HTTPS/TLS versions and cipher. May be the mail server was updated and now only accepts modern TLS versions and ciphers not supported by your old device.

Comment: Gmail. Is there no way to get auto emails on Android 5? It seems to me that other apps send notifications that need internet pretty quick

Comment: Is there a reason you use GMail with the stock mail app and not the GMail app?

Comment: I can not find a way to customize the notification sound when an email arrives (I want to play an mp3 when I get an email from a specific sender).